# Is there any important missable item in Final Fantasy X?

Tags: final-fantasy-10

I just started up Final Fantasy X again, I finished it a few years ago. Unless I'm thinking about a different game, I missed an item or items that where important for getting the best weapons(?) and it was past the part where I could get them.

I am right that there are some items that can be missed that you can't ever go back and get? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's a list of all permanently missable items in the game.

- a no encounter weapon, as an equipment drop from Geosgaeno.
- a magic counter buckler, from the hovercraft merchant in the Calm Lands.
- the 0-Slotted Longsword can't be bought after a certain point.
- Master Spheres are limited in quantity.
- the four Al Bhed Primers from 19 till 22 are (technically) missable.

Also, certain non-items are also permanantly missable.

- Having Wantz in Macalania Woods selling 4 slot equipment
- You can't recruit Durren for your Blitz team anymore after a certain point.

For more information, there is a [FAQ on GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/974868-final-fantasy-x-x-2-ultimate-box/faqs/48190) giving detailed information for all of these items

Comment: Don't know if this counts as an item? But you can only win that Blitzball game once? (The first tournament, which is compulsory to play). If you win you get a trophy

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is the part of Tidus' ultimate weapon. You can still get it later but the entrance to where the chest is is guarded by the Dark Aeon which is quite difficult to beat.

Comment: Very after the fact, but it's worth pointing out that not every release of the game has the Dark Aeons in it.  (Most notably for a good chunk of the audience of this site, the only version released in the US doesn't have them.)

Answer (score 0):

One thing that jumps to my mind is one of Wakka's weapon "Rematch" which is the earliest item in the game to have Evade & Counter.

After you defeat Isaaru with Yuna in Via Purifico, you will control Wakka's team, the weapon will be in a chest after killing Evrea (if you use the trigger command during the battle the chest will disappear)

Answer (score 0):

If you somehow miss the destructions sphere item in Bevelle, you can never go back and thus never get Anima. Can't remember if you can't get magus sisters without anima or not. I believe you can also miss getting the jecht shot but I'm not sure on this...

Comment: Yes, the Jecht Shot is missable. If you either don't go up to the ball on the deck to start the mini-sequence, or if you start it but fail for some reason (I have done both), you will miss out on the Jecht Shot. I do believe you can get Jecht Shot 2 regardless, though.

Comment: This is not true. There are two items in the Bevelle temple, and one of them (a sphere) is absolutely required to get before you can finish it. The other item, a lance, is not mandatory, but not getting it will still let you get Anima and the Magus Sisters.

Answer (score 0):

Heres everything i can think of after a look at my last playthroughs notes in order of appearance :

- 0-Slotted Longsword   (if sold) can buy it in Macalania Agency Shop until getting the airship (Macalania Lake)
- Primer XIX (Bevelle)
- The Equipment dropped from fiends underwater in the Via Purifico in Bevelle is appently impossible to find or create by any other means
- Primer XX  (Home)
- Primer XXI  (Home)
- Primer XXII  (Home)
- Magic Counter Buckler from Mobile Agency Shop (Calm Lands)
- Wantz (merchant)      Apperances on Mt Gagazet & Macalania Woods
- Durren (blitz player) Leaves after entering Sin (Calm Lands Gorge)
- No Encounters Weapon  from Geosengo (Baaja Temple)
- Weapon drops with +10% Critical Bonus from Penance (Monster Arena)
- Farming Dark Yojimbo (dont kill him the 5th time)
- Master Sphere's        from Dark Aeons/Monster Arena ect are technically limited

Dark Aeon interference :

- Besaid DST/Fayth chamber, Jecht Sphere #1, Energy Blast (Overdrive), Viluca(blitzplayer) , Primer II (Blocked by Dark Valefor)
- Macalania DST/Fayth chamber (blocked by Dark Shiva)
- Sun Crest (Zanarkand) (blocked by Dark Bahmut)

Answer (score 0):

Lulu's Celestial weapon; onion knight. Blocked by dark Ixion if encountered first as lightning strikes will stop until it is defeated.